# how to parse human input datetime ranges

Tags: python, api, parsing, datetime

I want to parse strings like this into a consistent structured date range:

- Monday through Wednesday, 10 - 6
- Monday - Saturday, 10 AM - 8 PM
- Monday and Tuesday 10AM-7PM
- Monday-Wednesday: 10am to 7pm

Any existing API's or libraries you can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) library. This does exactly what you said.